# How do I open a modal with a specific modal tab displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a link that is trying to open a specific modal tab but it always shows the first tab. Here is my code

Link

```
<a href="{{ url('/app') }}" data-target="#modal-faq" data-toggle="modal" id="footer-b-tab">
TAB B
</a>
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade modal-faq pr-0" id="modal-faq" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header border-0 pt-0">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills w-100 faq-nav-pills border-bottom" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item col-6 border-right px-0 faq-nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-a-tab" data-toggle="pill"
             href="#pills-a" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-a" aria-selected="true">
            <span class="title text-type-bold text-danger">TAB A</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item col-6 px-0 faq-nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-center" id="pills-b-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-b" role="tab"
             aria-controls="pills-b" aria-selected="false">
            <span class="title text-type-bold text-danger">TAB B</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

JQuery

```
 $('#footer-b-tab').on('click', function () {
$('#pills-b-tab').tab('show')})
```

Comment: When i run your code, It works just fine it shows tab b. Have you included the bootstrap js file?

Comment: Yes bootstrap js file is included